# Updating Data in Mysql through php on a current page

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hey All i have an issue while updating a data in MYSQL from front end php when i click once it update data when i click again without any change it again update and bring previous data. I am beginner to php and do not know what is the problem as code have no error and no warning please help and guide thanks and appreciation  for your time in Advance

My code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Update in PHP</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php
  $servername="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $conn=mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
  
 if(!$conn ) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

  $sq1 = 'select * from biodata';
  mysql_select_db('firstdb');
  $display=mysql_query($sq1,$conn);

 if(!$display ) {
 
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    exit;
 }

 if (mysql_num_rows($display) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
 }
?>
 

<table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Fname</th>
          <th>Lname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Message</th>
    <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $display ) ){
            echo
            "<form method= 'post' />
    <tr>
       <td><input name='UID' value='{$row['ID']}' /></td>
       <td><input name='upfname' value='{$row['fname']}' /></td>
       <td><input name='uplname' value='{$row['lname']}' /></td>
       <td><input name='upemail' value='{$row['email']}' /></td>
       <td><input name='upphone' value='{$row['phone']}' /></td>
       <td><input name='upmessage' value='{$row['message']}' /></td> 
       <td><input type='Submit' name='update' value='Update' id='".$row["ID"]."' </td> 
     </tr>
    </form>";
          }
?>
      </tbody>
</table>
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
  {
   
   $id   = $_REQUEST['UID'];
    $upfn = $_REQUEST['upfname'];
   $upln = $_REQUEST['uplname'];
          $upem = $_REQUEST['upemail'];
   $upph = $_REQUEST['upphone'];
   $upms = $_REQUEST['upmessage'];
   
   $up="UPDATE biodata 
   SET
   fname='$upfn',
   lname='$upln',
   email='$upem',
   phone='$upph',
   message='$upms' 
   WHERE ID = $id";
   $updbb=mysql_query($up,$conn);
   
   

   
   }
?>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need the ajax of jquery.

Comment: but i want it through PHP

Comment: whats your problem here? you don't want to send the form if data is not change?

Comment: @Masroor_Shah is it updating the database correctly ?

Comment: Yes  updating data is correctly but when i click again it brings previous data

Comment: put `if(isset($_REQUEST['update']` loop above all (just after connection to sql is done)

Comment: @Reoxy i done updating data when button clicked popUp will open when u update in popup changes should also made in main page and I successfully done that but now i want to update in current page without any popup or navigating to other pages

Comment: @ jitendrapurohit bro that make an error ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\Prac\updateinsamepage.php on line 38

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @aldrin27 Thank you Sir done i redirect the same page again and solved thank you so so much

Comment: Please refer me some good books or Website to get complete command on PHP  
my email is masroorsherazi12@gmail.com

Comment: @jitendrapurohit Please refer me some good books or Website to get complete command on PHP  
my email is masroorsherazi12@gmail.com

Comment: @aldrin27 Please refer me some good books or Website to get complete command on PHP my email is masroorsherazi12@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect the same page

header('Location: url'); like header('Location: inbox.php?u='.$log_username.'');